# Is it possible to do following in excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set cell_range=activecell

Range("o18").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=iferror(RC[-4]*RC[-3]-RC[-4]*RC[-3]*RC[-1]%,0)"


Range("O18").Select



Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O18:O52"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I want to change O52 to cell_range but it shows error.

Answer (score 1):

set 2 variabves - activecell row and acivecesll column and set autofill range via Cells()

```
aRow=Activecell.Row
aCol=Activecell.Column
.... 
and Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(18,15),Cells(aRow,aCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
```